# Testing trained model on the image from the test set

Tags: python, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

I trained my EfficientNet (CNN) and got accuracy=0.73. The question is how to check it on one concrete image from the testing set? How to write a code in python for it?
I described the testing set this way:

```
testing_data = np.load("testing_data.npy", allow_pickle = True)
test_X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in testing_data]).view(-1, 3, 224, 224)
test_y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in testing_data])
```

This one (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html ch5) doesn't work for me because I didn't use torch.utils.data.DataLoader in the previous code. My model is called net. I only tried something like this:

```
net(test_X[0])
```

but got an error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 3, 3, 3], but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 224, 224] instead
```

Comment: May you develop on what your problem is ? `net(test_X[0])` should work, does it returns an error ? Maybe you need to use `x = torch.unsqueeze(test_X[0])` in case you have dimension issues.

Comment: @Ubikuity I'm getting this error: "Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 3, 3, 3], but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 224, 224] instead" what is quite strange for me

Comment: As i mentioned in the previous comment, `x = torch.unsqueeze(test_X[0])` should do the job. Your network is expecting 4 dimensions [batch_size, 3, ,224, 224] and you feed a [3, 224, 224] input, so he can't compute. unsqueeze adds an empty dimension, that will be read as batch_size by your network. use `x = torch.unsqueeze(test_X[0])` and then try sending x into your network.

Comment: @Ubikuity what should I write as dim? Because "unsqueeze() missing 1 required positional arguments: "dim" "

Comment: Maybe `x = torch.unsqueeze(test_X[0], 0)`. Second argument corresponds to where we add the empty dimension, which is the first slot (index 0) in our case.

Comment: @Ubikuity It worked, but now I'm got such an output: [-0.0166,  1.0421,  0.0242] and I'm using one hot vector for 3 classes. How to interpret this result? :D I'm really new in this field, sorry. It means second class I think as the biggest number here.

Comment: I don't know what your network is supposed to do, this outputs looks like a classification output where the 1 output is the detected class, so here it means this image belongs to class nº2. We usually use `torch.argmax(output)` to get the maximum of this vector, which is the detected class. doc of this function is right here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmax.html

Comment: @Ubikuity, ok thank you very much! :) Your answers were very very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome :)